# Pourquoi l'adjectif se rapportant aux glandes est « glandulaire » et non « glandaire » ?

Tags: étymologie, adjectifs

Pourquoi l'adjectif qui se rapporte aux glandes est devenu « glandulaire » et non « *glandaire » ?
On croirait que « glandulaire » aurait rapport aux « glandules » qui sont un sous-ensemble des glandes. Est-ce parce que « *glandaire » pourrait vouloir dire « relatif aux glands » ?

Y a-t-il une règle en français qui interdise la formation du mot « glandaire » comme adjectif relié aux glandes ?

Comment: *Glandaire* a été effectivement utilisé pour dire relatif aux glands (zoologie, qui se nourrit de glands), ou relatif au gland  (le gland en anatomie), mais je pense que c'est tombé en désuétude. Par contre je serais étonné que ce soit la raison pour ne pas utiliser le mot en rapport aux glandes.

Comment: @None Vieilli oui c'est ce que j'ai trouvé.  10 millions de glandeurs : )

Answer (score 1):

La morphologie se rapporte à l'adjectif formulé à cause du radical en latin surtout avec la racine qui termine en -l. (Le nom
en français *glande* et puis glandule qui veut dire petite glande, c'est la même racine.). Les adjectifs suivent le modèle angle, angulaire, cercle, circulaire .  On note aussi le suffixe -eux dans ce cas.  [Dans l'article "-AIRE1,, suff."](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Glandulaire), mon emphase en gras :

> Étymol. ET HIST. A.− Étymologie 1. Remonte, dans bon nombre de mots
> (de formation sav.), au lat. -āris (issu de -ālis **apr. un rad. en
> -l)** : canicularis « caniculaire » > caniculaire capillaris « qui concerne les cheveux » > capillaire capularis « de bière, de cercueil
> » circularis « circulaire » > circulaire cul(l)earis « de la grandeur
> d'une outre » diobolaris « qu'on a pour deux oboles » doliaris «
> relatif au dolium, de tonneau » exemplaris « qui sert de modèle » >
> exemplaire insularis « insulaire » > insulaire piacularis « expiatoire
> » popularis « qui a trait au peuple » > populaire proelaris « de
> combat » triangularis « triangulaire » > triangulaire vulgaris « qui
> concerne la foule » >
>
> − **Noter aussi les changements dus à l'utilisation de rad. sav. dans** :
> angle/angulaire, cercle/circulaire, muscle/musculaire,
> peuple/populaire, spectacle/spectaculaire. **C.− Affinités morphol. avec
> d'autres suff. − -ule** : globulaire, lobulaire, vermiculaire ... . On
> ne le rencontre jamais après des dér. en -iste, -ure, -ance/ -ence.
>
> Rem. 3. Concurrence avec les suff. adj. -eux, -ique, -al/-el. −
> L'oppos. -aire/-eux est relativement nette. En effet, le suff. -eux
> exprime gén. l'idée de plénitude mêlée à celle d'abondance ou
> d'importance, tandis que le suff. -aire exprime les rapp. les plus
> divers : 
> angulaire « qui forme un angle » / anguleux « plein d'aspérités »
> lobulaire « qui a la forme d'un lobule » / lobuleux « composé de lobules »
> musculaire « relatif aux muscles » / musculeux « qui a des muscles développés »
> populaire « propre au peuple » / populeux « très peuplé »
>
> **[glandulaire](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Glandulaire) /glanduleux« qui a la nature ou la forme d'une glande »**

> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi), [*-aire*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-aire) ]

Donc [glande](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/glande) > glandule > glandulaire à cause de la racine *glandula* en latin.

> Glandre est issu du lat. méd. glandula (Celse), dimin. de glans
> (gland*), avec dissimilation du second -l-. Étant donné qu'en a. fr.
> gland et glande sont chacun attestés aux deux sens de « gland » et de
> « glande » (T.-L.), il est probable que l'a. fr. glande est issu de
> glans, glandis adapté en lat. vulg. à la 1redéclinaison, d'autant plus
> facilement qu'il était fém. (FEW t. 4, p. 149a); glandre, glande, issu
> de glandula, se serait ensuite confondu avec glande issu de glanda

> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi), [*glande*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/glande/0) ]

[Glandaire](https://www.littre.org/definition/glandaire) (qui vit des glandes) a un autre sens.

Comment: http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/grand-larousse/glandaire

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t D'acc j'ai mis le même liens à la même citation de CNRTL plus haut dans la réponse, c'est ça ?  Maintenant il y a quatre liens dont un se répète, chu pas sûre d'avoir fait ce que tu cherches.